# HAPROXY how to listen api rest

Tags: rest, haproxy

I'm trying to listen API rest with HAPROXY. I don't know if this can be possible, its my first problem, i read about api rest to check logs of HAPROXY.

example:

```
listen IAM *:5000
  bind *:5000
  balance roundrobin
  server node1.openiam.com 10.10.0.0:9080 check fall 5 inter 2000 rise 2
  server node2.openiam.com 10.10.0.1:9080 check fall 5 inter 2000 rise 2
```

but I wanna consume api rest to check the health of server:

```
curl -v XGET 'http://dev1.openiamdemo.com:8080/idp/oauth2/userinfo?token=rdSOyor6hqJ2CrQ5QrpeXgX.ItgVEx1.nskN'
```

can be done?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It resolved with the next configuration: 
 Haproxy call webservice with token

```
    option httpchk GET /webconsole/rest/api/system/system/info?token=****
    server nodo1 10.10.x.x:8080 check
```